# media metadata observable map is null in java fx media

Tags: javafx-2

Hi guys I tried to play a song and print its metadata using java fx 2.1 api using the following code

```
    Media media = new Media(UIandControls.class.getResource("/assets/testData/mom.mp3").toExternalForm());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    ObservableMap list=media.getMetadata();
         System.out.print(list);
         mediaPlayer.play();
```

for some reason getMetadata() is empty observable Map.

Output looks like this

> {}

plz help me.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Need to call mediaPlayer.play() before retrieving metadata.

Comment: Would be nice if you extended this answer so it is more in depth higher quality.

Comment: Seriously?? Isn't that stupid.. Get all media files. Then play each of them to collect metadata

Comment: As i also having the same issue, I applied mediaPlayer.play() as like of what you have mentioned but still it output is blank {}, i am using mp4 file

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles with this at first but I found that using this worked.

```
mediaPlayer.getMedia().getMetadata().addListener(new MapChangeListener<String, Object>(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ?> change) {
            if(change.wasAdded()){
                if(change.getKey().equals("artist"))
                    setArtist(change.getValueAdded().toString());
                else if(change.getKey().equals("title"))
                    setTitle(change.getValueAdded().toString());
                else if(change.getKey().equals("year"))
                    setYear(change.getValueAdded().toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Also I read that the media data won't always be there right after initialization, therefore calling the `mediaPlayer.setOnReady()` method can make sure that the data is there.

Example:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setTrackLength(mediaPlayer.getMedia().getDuration().toMinutes());
            mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(progressChangeListener);
        }
    });
```